# Glassfish: Illegal character in path at index 11: commons-logging-1.1.jar?

Tags: java, glassfish-3, apache-commons-logging

So I'm about to develop a Spring MVC web application. But there is an exception everytime I deploy the app which says:

> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 11: file:/E:/My Documents/NetBeansProjects/ProjectName/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar.

So I thought maybe the jar is corrupted so I downloaded another jar file which also have the same problem. What's causing this?

The web app itself works just fine tho. But still that exception annoys me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the space at index 11, spaces is not valid in a uri, encode the space

```
file:/E:/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/ProjectName/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
```

Comment: Hmm, where do i encode it? I just had it automatically built using Netbeans.

Comment: use a path without spaces perhaps?